What is the interpretation of the covariance of two quantum observables?
I have been studying the covariance matrix in continuous variable quantum systems and I am struggling to understand the interpretation of this object. In statistics the covariance measures the joint variability of two random variables $A$ and $B$ and is defined as
$$ \mathrm{cov}(A,B) = \mathbb{E} \left[ ( A - \mathbb{E}(A) ) (B - \mathbb{E}(B) \right] \tag{1} $$
where $\mathbb{E}$ denotes the expectation value. In quantum mechanics, the covariance of two operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ is given by
$$ \mathrm{cov}(\hat{A},\hat{B}) =  \frac{1}{2} \langle \{ \hat{A} - \langle \hat{A} \rangle , \hat{B} - \langle \hat{B} \rangle \} \rangle \tag{2} $$
where $\langle O \rangle = \langle \psi | O |\psi\rangle$ is the expectation value with respect to the state of the system. See Eq. (B.4) of this review on CVQKD.
Now I would expect that (2) describes the same thing as (1). When measuring a quantum system, you cause the wavefunction to collapse and obtain a classical quantity: the measurement outcome. This is a random variable as the wavefunction collapse is random, so I am sampling a random variable from a given distribution and the fact it came from a quantum system does not seem to be important here as I could pass this data onto someone else who doesn't know where I obtained it from who constructs the covariance matrix of the data using (1). Therefore, I would expect that if I calculate the covariance of my classical measurement outcomes and use equation (1), I should be able to mould it into equation (2). However, I cannot show this. Below I give my attempt.
My attempt to show equivalence
Suppose I have a quantum system in the state $|\psi\rangle$ and for simplicity assume that $\langle \hat{A} \rangle = \langle \hat{B} \rangle = 0$, in which case
$$ \mathrm{cov}(\hat{A},\hat{B}) = \frac{1}{2} \left( \langle \hat{A} \hat{B} \rangle + \langle \hat{B} \hat{A} \rangle \right), $$
which is what I attempt to show starting from equation (1). As I am measuring two observables, I will have a joint probability distribution $p_{AB}(a,b)$ defined as the probability that when I measure the system I get the outcomes $a$ and $b$. From this distribution, I can write down statistical definition of covariance from (1) as
$$ \mathrm{cov}(A,B) = \sum_{a,b} p_{AB}(a,b) ab. \tag{3}$$
Now I have to be careful about my measurement order, as $[\hat{A},\hat{B}] \neq 0$ in general. Let me choose to measure $\hat{A}$ first and $\hat{B}$ second. The first measurement will collapse the state $|\psi\rangle$ into an eigenstate $|a\rangle$ of $\hat{A}$ with eigenvalue $a$, with a probability
$$ p_A(a) = |\langle a | \psi\rangle|^2, $$
and the measurement of $\hat{B}$ will be done immediately after, but now the state has collapsed to $|a\rangle$ from the previous measurement, so we have the conditional probability
$$ p_{B|A}(b|a) = | \langle b | a \rangle |^2.$$
Therefore, the probability to measure $a$ and $b$ in the order $\hat{A}$ first and $\hat{B}$ second is
$$ p_{AB}(a,b) = p_{B|A}(b|a)p_A(a). $$
If I substitute this back into (3) I get
$$ 
\begin{align}
\mathrm{cov}(A,B)  & = \sum_{a,b} ab  | \langle b | a \rangle |^2 |\langle a | \psi\rangle|^2 \\
 &= \sum_{a,b} ab \langle b | a \rangle \langle a | b \rangle \langle \psi | a \rangle \langle a | \psi\rangle \\
& = \sum_{a} a \langle a | \left( \sum_b b |b\rangle \langle b |\right) | a \rangle \langle \psi | a \rangle \langle a | \psi \rangle \\
& = \langle \psi |  \left( \sum_a a \langle a | \hat{B} | a \rangle |a \rangle \langle a | \right) |\psi\rangle \\
& \neq \langle \hat{B}\hat{A} \rangle
\end{align}$$
If I measure in the reverse order, I won't get $\langle \hat{A} \hat{B} \rangle$ either. My thoughts were that the anti-commutator had something to do with the fact that the two measurements can be done in two ways (it also keeps the object hermitian).
My questions
As you can see this calculation failed to derive (2). I have read this answer that joint probability distributions of non-commuting variables are not defined. What I have done above by defining my "joint probability distibution" does not describe measuring two observables at the same time, but instead describes measuring one then measuring another, which seems like something you'd do in the lab to construct a covariance. However, it does not reproduce the quantum covariance from equation (2). I break my question down:

If I inserted my classical measurements into (1), would I get (2)?
If not, what is the interpretation of (2)?
How would I measure this in an experiment if I cannot measure observables simultaneously?

